# Android mediaPlayer not being correctly released

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play a sound in an android widget on a button click, this is my current code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Boolean hasToPlayMedia = false;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    if (intent.getAction().equals("somevalue")) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.somevalue);
        hasToPlayMedia = true;
    // OTher conditionals here
    }
    if (hasToPlayMedia) {
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
                mp = null;
            }
        });
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

However, in the console I read:

```
E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
W/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ MediaPlayer finalized without being released
```

and sometimes after a while clicking the button doesn't play the sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep a static reference to your MediaPlayer inside your class and outside the method scope. Otherwise, the OS may clean its resources and then when you try to access it from inside the onCompletion() method, it will be in an illegal state.

Comment: Same thing, seems the class is reinstanciated every time, if I set as a class variable, on the second tap (during the first execution, so before the `OnCompletionListener` nulling mediaPlayer) the variable is null already

Comment: I ended up using a static variable, please say that in the answer

Comment: Of course. If you for example pass between activities such that the onDestroy() of an activity is called, then globals which aren't static will be cleared as well. If it's a MediaPlayer that's used throughout the application, you may want to save it in the Application class of your project, or in a base class of all your activities (as static global variable).